# foreach loop not working with laravel queue

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using `sync` (local driver) for pushing up a queue in a `update` method of `EmailCampaignController`, which uses another method of the same controller named `emailQueue`

like this

```
Queue::push('EmailNewsletterController@emailQueue', array('campaign_id' => $campaign_id));
```

The `emailQueue` uses a `foreach` loop which runs correctly for once after that it gives error as if the `$campaign_id` is undefined

here is the `emailQueue` method

```
public function emailQueue($job, $data) {

    // Queue Starts here

    $emailCampaign = EmailCampaign::find($data['campaign_id']);
    $emailCampaign->status = 'In Progress';
    $emailCampaign->last_activity = Carbon::now();

    $emailCampaign->save();

    $data = $emailCampaign->emailCampaignNewsletter;

    $contacts = $emailCampaign->contactList->contacts;

    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
        $emailBody = [
            'message' => [
                'subject' => $data['email_title'],
                'html' => $data['email_body'],
                'from_email' => $data['from_email'],
                'to' => [['email' => $contact['email_address']]]
            ]
        ];

        $response = Mandrill::request('messages/send', $emailBody);

        EmailCampaignRecord::create([
            'email_campaign_id' => $data['campaign_id'],
            'mandrill_email_id' => $response[0]->_id,
            'status' => $response[0]->status,
            'to_email' => $contact['email_address']
        ]);

        $contact->last_activity = Carbon::now();
        $contact->save();

    }

    $emailCampaign->status = 'Sent';
    $emailCampaign->save();

    $job->delete();

// Ends here

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? why is it not working like a normal loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `email_campaign_id` to be null because `$data['campaign_id']` was null the correct foreign key was `$data['email_campaign_id']` that's what stopped the process - I should have tested it before putting it in the queue

after changing the code

```
EmailCampaignRecord::create([
        'email_campaign_id' => $data['campaign_id'],
        'mandrill_email_id' => $response[0]->_id,
        'status' => $response[0]->status,
        'to_email' => $contact['email_address']
    ]);
```

to

```
EmailCampaignRecord::create([
        'email_campaign_id' => $data['email_campaign_id'],
        'mandrill_email_id' => $response[0]->_id,
        'status' => $response[0]->status,
        'to_email' => $contact['email_address']
    ]);
```

the problem was solved